# What is the C++ equivalent to this MATLAB code?

Tags: c++, matlab, serial-communication

In my project, I am responsible for migrating some MATLAB code to C++. The code below refers to serial communication from a computer to a microcontroller.  The function `CreatePackage` generates a package which is then sent to the microcontroller using MATLAB's *fwrite(serial)* function.

```
function package = CreatePackage(V)
for ii = 1:size(V,2)
    if V(ii) > 100
        V(ii) = 100;
    elseif V(ii) < -100
        V(ii) = -100;
    end
end

vel = zeros(1, 6);
for ii = 1:size(V,2)
    if V(ii) > 0
        vel(ii) = uint8(V(ii));
    else
        vel(ii) = uint8(128 + abs(V(ii)));
    end
end

package = ['BD' 16+[6, vel(1:6)], 'P' 10 13]+0;
```

And then, to send the package:

```
function SendPackage(S, Package)

for ii = 1:length(S)
    fwrite(S(ii), Package);
end
```

How can I create an array/vector in C++ to represent the `package` variable used in the MATLAB code above?

I have no experience with MATLAB so any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: A good C++ reference will show how to use `std::vector`.

Comment: A search of the internet for keywords "c++ matlab array vector" should show some relevant examples.

Comment: My main doubt is what type would that vector would be... integer, char?

Comment: Malab is almost entirely floating point. I'd start with `double` and go from there. Strongly recommend spending some time familiarizing yourself with Matlab. It will hep you quite a bit.

Comment: I would _not_ start with double. Yes, MATLAB uses double by default, but this question deals with streaming unsigned integer data (i.e. uint8). Looking into floating point specifications is going to set leandrocoutom backwards here.

Comment: While a good C++ reference will show how to use `std::vector`, I don't think that is what is needed here.  The issue is that the word _vector_ denotes different things depending if you are talking in regard to C++ (abstract data type, sequence container) or MATLAB (single dimension, typical numeric, array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `package` variable is being streamed as 12, unsigned 8-bit integers in your MATLAB code, so I would use a `char[12]` array in C++.  You can double check `sizeof(char)` on your platform to ensure that `char` is only 1 byte.

Yes, MATLAB default data-type is a `double`, but that does not mean your vector V isn't filled with integer values.  You have to look at this data or the specs from your equipment to figure this out.

Whatever the values are coming in, you are setting/clipping the outgoing range to [-100, 100] and then offsetting them to the byte range [0, 255].

If you do not know a whole lot about MATLAB, you may be able to leverage what you know from C++ and use C as an interim.  MATLAB's fwrite functionality lines up with that of C's, and you can include these functions in C++ with the `#include<cstdio.h>` preprocessor directive.

Here is an example solution:

```
#include <cstdio.h>    // fwrite 
#include <algorithm>  // min, max
...

void makeAndSendPackage(int * a6x1array, FILE * fHandles, int numHandles){

   char packageBuffer[13] = {'B','D',24,0,0,0,0,0,0,'P','\n','\r',0};

   for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
       int tmp = a6x1array[i];
       packageBuffer[i+3] = tmp<0: abs(max(-100,tmp))+144 ? min(100,tmp)+16;
   }

   for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
       fwrite(fHandles[i],"%s",packageBuffer);
   }

}
```

Let me know if you have questions about the above code.

Comment: Thank you very much! The serial communication worked now in C++ thanks to you, nice job! (You forgot the 'P' in the array but that was fine). Thanks again for giving your time to help me.

Comment: Ah, so I did.  I'll fix that for completeness.  Glad you got working.  I am not quite sure why the question is still on hold, as there was enough information to answer it, but so be it.